# OAuth and public keys

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, oauth

I get the basic OAuth and PKI flow and the different actors involved but I'm still unsure how public/private keys play a role.

When a client identifies itself upon registration with a certified public key, is that key then bound to the access token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Prereqs:**

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work) for a rough overview of how OAuth works.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853889/how-does-public-key-cryptography-work) for a rough overview of how public key SSL/TLS works.

See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/how-does-an-ssl-server-prove-its-identity) for a rough overview of how SSL certificates relate to identity.

**The meat of the matter:**

Public/Private key systems can be used to provide three kinds of services:

1. symmetric session encryption
2. asymmetric session encryption
3. identity verification (often coupled with authentication)

Technically, none of the above three services are required for an OAuth system to work properly - it's very possible to build an OAuth system which doesn't use public/private keys for anything, at all.

That said, OAuth systems will often rely on property 1 of public/private key systems to ensure that OAuth related communication is encrypted, usually by building communication protocols on top of existing TLS/SSL based systems. They will also often rely on property 3 to provide one-sided identity verification, usually by relying on external, built in browser components, which implicitly perform that function.

Comment: that cleared up alot :) thnx